# Web search in an iPhone app

Tags: iphone

I've got experience in C/C++ and am trying to now learn Objective-C for iPhone development.  I have very little web design experience.

I'm trying to create an app for a friend's site that accesses a search feature from a website and then display the results in a UITableView.  For example, (this isn't the site I'll be using, but...) using the stackoverflow search function and then being able to format the results (https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=iphone+web+search) in cells.  I'd like to leave out the rest of the content on the page.

I've only been able to find info about reading xml or rss search results.  Otherwise, I could use UIWebView, but that displays the entire site.  Are there other classes that I should look into for doing this?  Any help would be very, very much appreciated!

Comment: What sort of site are you trying to display search results for? Scraping a web page is difficult in any case. Is there a search API for the site that you'd have access to? It would be massively easier to parse an XML or JSON result list...

Comment: It's for a catalog like this: http://regina.stmarytx.edu/

Answer (score 0):

The iPhone SDK doesn't include Cocoa libraries for parsing HTML. Just NSXMLParser, which isn't a good tool for what you want to do. (It will choke on valid HTML that isn't valid XML.)

[This page](http://vgable.com/blog/2009/05/01/nsxmlparser-and-htmlxhtml/) is probably a good first place to look. The author says, "For scraping/reading a webpage, [XPath](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/using-libxml2-for-parsing-and-xpath.html) is the best choice. It is faster and less memory intensive then NSXMLParser, and very concise. My experience with it has been positive."